# Backbone.js: Multiple delete with 1 request

Tags: backbone.js

I have a backbone.js application connecting to a REST API. I noticed that if you delete multiple models at once, seperate API request have to be sent for each model.

Is there any way to handle the delete request using 1 request?

Comment: Did you get it working?? If possible can you share some knowledge?

Comment: currently just passing the ids I want to delete as parameters. Not the cleanest method but it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need your server to expose an endpoint for deleting multiple models at once by passing IDs of the models to be deleted in the first place. If you have this available the common way to handle that would be to add a method to your collection called something along the lines of `deleteByIds` which would accept array of IDs and then this method would remove the models from the collection on successful delete request (if sync) or straight away before sending the delete request to the API endpoint which would make sure they are all removed from the server.

By default that's how RESTful interfaces work and batch processing is always a custom extension to RESTful interfaces so there is no out of the box way to do that and it might involve you doing some extra work both on the backbone client and on the backend.

Comment: Whèn you say `which would accept array of IDs and then this method would remove the models from the collection `.. How do you call the method and pass `List<int>`?? Collection doesn't have a POST operation. Right?